# Add new row of input elements and table rows using JQuery

Tags: jquery, forms, html-table, expand

I have the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#add, .check ").click(function() {
            $('#mytable tbody>tr:last').clone(true).insertAfter('#mytable tbody>tr:last');
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

With the following in by body:

```
<form action='demo.php' method='post'>
 <a  id="add">+</a></td>
  <table id="mytable" width="300" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Name</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="person">
      <td><input type="text" name="name[]" class='check' /></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <input type='submit' />
</form>
```

How can I get it to clear the fields after adding them and maybe add an effect such as fade in or slide down, etc...  Also, I would like it if any form element in the last row is focused it will add a new row automatically, but cannot figure out how to access the last row's form elements... :\

Comment: I had landed on this page by while searching for a way to add a form to a table which already exists. I suspect your title isn't completely accurate, it seems your form already exists without the jQuery. Is this true? If so, would you consider changing the title?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate through the new values with a find like so. Check out this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UXun2/1/)

```
 $("#add, .check ").click(function() {
$('#mytable tbody>tr:last')
    .clone(true)
    .insertAfter('#mytable tbody>tr:last').find('input').each(function(){
        $(this).val('');
    });
});
```

If you want to make the new row appear on focus of the last row, you'll have to delegate the focus on the first input of the last row. You want to use delegate because the rows are dynamically added. You can also add the fadein effect after you insert the cloned row. Here is a [fiddle for this](http://jsfiddle.net/zGe8W/2/)

```
$("#mytable").delegate(' tbody>tr:last input:first','focus',function(){
    $('#mytable tbody>tr:last')
    .clone(true)
    .insertAfter('#mytable tbody>tr:last').hide().fadeIn().find('input').each(function(){
        $(this).val('');
    });
});
```

Comment: That does seem to work however not all the time (I am using FireFox 3.6).  It starts then seems to break, yet it throws no errors and prevents the `$('#add')` from working as well.

Comment: The fadein effect needs to finish before executing the new row. If you tab too quickly it'll clone/bind funny and break. You can  modify it not to do so for example only binding the focus when the row has faded in. Here is a fiddle without the effect, it looks like it works http://jsfiddle.net/zGe8W/3/